# How do I access both associations in a self referential has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have an association class like:

```
class TranslationAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :child, class_name: "Translation"
  belongs_to :translation
```

And a class like:

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :translation_associations
  has_many :children, through: :translation_associations
```

I get the children just fine.  But if I am a child, how do I create a relationship to get the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Translation class to following code

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :translation_associations
  has_many :children, through: :translation_associations
  has_many :parent_associations, class_name:'TranslationAssociation', foreign_key:'child_id'
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_associations, source: :translation
```

You can learn more about relationships in rails in rails guides.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference